# R kmeans NAs in foreign function call (arg 13) error

Tags: r

I have numeric data in a vector and I'm trying to run kmeans on it. The following gives an error

```
> kmeans( mydata, centers = 2 ) # trying centers 2 to 20 but failing at 2
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NAs in foreign function call (arg 13)
In addition: Warning message:
In do_one(nmeth) : NAs introduced by coercion

> str(mydata)
 num [1:44990687] 3.44e-06 3.44e-06 3.44e-06 3.44e-06 4.35e-05 ...
> is.numeric(mydata)
[1] TRUE
```

My code works for the datasets that are smaller than this one, so I suspect it may have something to do with the size of the data. Any ideas on how to fix the error? Thanks in advance.

Update:
I've tried the following:

```
> x <- length(mydata)
> kmeans( mydata[1:(x/2)], centers = 2 )
> kmeans( mydata[(x/2):x], centers = 2 )
```

Both calls to kmeans finish with no errors. So it does look like it has something to do with the size of the data and not the format/types. If that's the case, what should I do to be able to handle it?
Thanks again.

Comment: If nrows(mydata) > 2^31, then this is a bug introduced in R 3.0.2. Check here (https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15364#c6) for details. For now you can use other algorithms of k-means such as Lloyd or MacQueen, these will work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [kmeans on 46 million elements coerces NA values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952232/kmeans-on-46-million-elements-coerces-na-values)

Answer (score 2):

Try using a previous version of R, like 2.15.3. That worked for me.

I had similar issues using the most current version as of this writing, v3.1.2 and it recreated the NA coercion issue.

I created a similar thread here:
[kmeans on 46 million elements coerces NA values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952232/kmeans-on-46-million-elements-coerces-na-values/)

Comment: Thanks. I have to try it sometime and follow up here.

Answer (score 2):

This has been a bug introduced (by me) into R 3.0.1 when I fixed another bug. http://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15364#c6
contains the original bug report and Gökcen Eraslan's report about this problem.

The bug has been fixed 10 minutes ago in R 3.2.0 alpha (to appear as R 3.2.0 in about two weeks).   Note however that your `nrow(x)` was already within a factor of <= 50 of the maximal 32 bit integer (2^31 - 1) which is a strict upper limit for the number of rows for the default `kmeans()` algorithm in R, as it is currently using standard Fortran which does not allow larger matrix dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error and when I read the error log it says NaN which mean Not a Number. So I double check my data set and yes, there's a row that contains a String (words). I remove that String and it works perfectly.