# kmeans on 46 million elements coerces NA values

Tags: r

Simply running

```
kmeans(runif(46e6), 2)
```

results in an error:

```
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NAs in foreign function call (arg 13)
In addition: Warning message:
In do_one(nmeth) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

any thoughts? I've attached my session info below. I've only found one other thread mentioning this, with no answer: [R kmeans NAs in foreign function call (arg 13) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396234/r-kmeans-nas-in-foreign-function-call-arg-13-error). Clearly the input data is numeric...

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] zoo_1.7-11    rgdal_0.9-1   raster_2.3-12 sp_1.0-16    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.0      lattice_0.20-29 tools_3.1.0
```

EDIT: I had thought it was a memory issue. The machine used during my first attempt had 8GB. I updated R to the most current version of date 3.1.2 and it had the same issue.

I tried this on two other machines:

- The second attempt was on a windows machine with R 3.1.0 and 160GB of ram -- same error
- The third attempt was on another windows machine with R 2.15 and 63GM of ram -- it was successful.

Could this be something with version R.3.1 higher? Would be curious if others find similar results.

Thank you

Comment: When trying `kmeans` on 46e6, I got exactly the same error as you (my system is similar). When using only 23e6, it performed well the operation. I wonder if this too could be related to floating point problems on X64 windows machines (see for example Martin's answer in [cor sometimes generates NaN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745943/r-cor-returns-nan-sometimes)

Comment: Interesting .. try the same command on a previous R version like 2.15.3 -- it works for me. I reckon it could be something specific to the new R version as well

Comment: This is a bug introduced in R 3.0.2. Check here (https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15364#c6) for details. For now you can use other k-means algorithms such as Lloyd or MacQueen, these will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @gkcn correctly mentions above: This is a bug introduced in R 3.0.2,
which now has been fixed, and the upcoming R 3.2.0 will have the fix.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311530/161921.
Thank you, Gökcen Eraslan!